# Drawing Pencil-Style Algorithm - Fill the gaps, reducing points in lines

Tags: android, algorithm, drawing, paint

It's easy to track the movement on the screen with MotionEvents, take all the points that you're finger is at. But how can you easily identify drawing patterns so there doesn't have to be a single dot wherever you put your finger?

As of now, I draw a dot whenever the user touches the screen in my app. But if I quickly drag from top left corner to bottom right corner, there's "in between" empty spaces.

Are there any good algorithms, methods that can be used to calculate how many points are needed between setting down your finger on the screen until you've released it and fill in the gaps wherever there needs to be.

Say if I draw a 100% straight line, it should only be 2 points most likely, or doesn't need to have "anything" more than those two points of X, Y coordinates. Start coordinates and end coordinates.

It seems such a waste to draw a million dots to follow the user's movement and is expensive because there get to be so many dots on the screen when there doesn't need to be.

Pencil-style drawing style.

As of now, I'm working on this for Android. But I think it's more of a general question.

Comment: While this covers signature capture more so than arbitrary other types of drawing, it may be useful: http://corner.squareup.com/2012/07/smoother-signatures.html

Comment: you can draw lines between scanned points, but curves are visually better i use last 4 points as interpolation cubic and last segment is line until next point is added ... Do not use Bezier or SPLINEs because they do not go through your points which will be inconvenient during drawing ...

Answer (score 0):

What it sounds like you're looking for is a way to remove redundant points in a continuous path as a means of optimizing the path created by the user drawing on the screen.

There are trivial solutions for this and there are complicated ways to do this. Let's go for a simple approach that should be pretty effective.

Arrange your points into an array or some other ordered structure. Consider the following set of points:

A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F

To decide if "C" belongs in the list we need to work with C and it's two neighbors, B and D. These three points define two lines - BC and CD. What we want to know is if these two lines are colinear (i.e., do they lie on the same straight line.)

To determine if they are colinear, we just need to perform a dot product between the normals of the two vectors BC and CD, with C being the midpoint. If they are all on the same line, then the middle point (C) is redundant and can be removed. If you carefully loop over the entire list, you'll be able to remove all of the redundant points.

Here's some pseudo-code. For clarity, the three input parameters will be named B, C and D to match the description above. The result will be a numeric value, which I'll show you how to use:

```
double linearDotProduct(point B, point C, point D)
{
    // create our first vector (B->C) - we can use a point structure for this
    point BC(C.x - B.x, C.y - B.y)

    // normalize BC
    double lenBC = sqrt(BC.x * BC.x + BC.y * BC.y)
    BC.x /= lenBC
    BC.y /= lenBC

    // create our second vector (C->D) - we can use a point structure for this
    point CD(D.x - C.x, D.y - C.y)

    // normalize CD
    double lenCD = sqrt(CD.x * CD.x + CD.y * CD.y)
    CD.x /= lenCD
    CD.y /= lenCD

    // Perform a dot product
    double dot = BC.x * CD.x + BC.y * CD.y

    return dot
}
```

Calling this function with your three points will return a number in the range of `-1 ... +1`. A value of +1 means that the line segments AB and BC are traveling along the same exact line. However, because we're doing floating point math, you shouldn't just check for `== 1.0` because that will almost never be the case (floating point precision error.)

A better solution would be to use it like this:

```
double Epsilon = 0.00001 // Some small number greater than zero

if (linearDotProduct(B, C, D) > (1.0 - Epsilon))
{
    // safe to remove point B
}
```

You can adjust the amount of optimization by playing with `Epsilon`. The larger the epsilon value is, the more tolerance you'll allow. In other words, larger epsilon values will allow you to remove points that are "almost, but not entirely, straight". This allows you to get a bit more optimization from it. Play with the epsilon to find a result you're happy with.

This is a naive approach. Other approaches work similarly but take more points into account over a distance in order to determine how an entire segment matches the user's overall gesture. I won't cover them here because it doesn't sound like that's what you need, but just wanted you to know the limitations of what's presented.